# При клике на кнопку изменить ее имя и сделать ее неактивной пока не заполнены два input'а

Tags: javascript, input, button

Есть в форме два неактивных input'а (readonly). Есть также кнопка "изменить", при нажатии на которую input'ы становятся активными (снимается параметр readonly). Эта кнопка меняет свое название (на "сохранить"). Необходимо, чтобы эта кнопка оставалась неактивной, пока не заполнены оба input'а. Как только input'ы заполнены - делать ее активной.
Код пока вот такой.

```
<label id="pwmsg" for="password">Пароль</label>
<button type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-info">Изменить</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#edit").on("click",function() {
    var name = $("[id=password]")
    name.val("");
    name.focus();
    if (this.innerText=="Изменить") {
        this.innerText="Сохранить";
        $("[id=password]").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("[id=password]").attr("placeholder", "");
        $("[id=password2]").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("[id=password2]").attr("placeholder", "");
    }
    else {
      this.innerText="Изменить";
      $("[id=password]").attr("readonly","readonly");
      $("[id=password]").attr("placeholder", "Пароль изменен");
      $("[id=password2]").attr("readonly","readonly");
      $("[id=password2]").attr("placeholder", "Пароль изменен");
    }
  });
});
</script>
<input type="password" id="password" readonly placeholder="Скрыт в целях безопасности" value="" aria-required="true" class="error" aria-invalid="true" />
<label id="pw2msg" for="password2">Повторите пароль</label>
<input type="password" id="password2" readonly placeholder="Скрыт в целях безопасности" value="" aria-required="true" class="error" aria-invalid="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так.

Добавил условие чтоб пароли были равны

```js
let password = $("#password");
let password2 = $("#password2");

$(function() {
  $("#edit").on("click",function() {
    if (this.innerText=="Изменить") {
        this.innerText="Сохранить";
        password.removeAttr("readonly");
        password.attr("placeholder", "");
        password.val("");
        password.focus();
        
        password2.removeAttr("readonly");
        password2.attr("placeholder", "");
    }
    else {
      this.innerText="Изменить";
      password.val("");
      password.attr("placeholder", "Пароль изменен");
      password.attr("readonly","readonly");      
      password2.val("");
      password2.attr("placeholder", "Пароль изменен");
      password2.attr("readonly","readonly");
      
    }
  });
  
  password.keyup(checkPasswords);
  password2.keyup(checkPasswords);
  
  
  function checkPasswords(){
    if (password.attr("readonly") !== "readonly") {
      if (password.val().length > 0 && password2.val().length > 0
          && password.val() === password2.val()) {
            $("#edit").attr('disabled', false)
          } else {
            $("#edit").attr('disabled', true);
          }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="pwmsg" for="password">Пароль</label>
<button type="button" id="edit" class="btn btn-info">Изменить</button>

<input type="password" id="password" readonly placeholder="Скрыт в целях безопасности" value="" aria-required="true" class="error" aria-invalid="true" />

<label id="pw2msg" for="password2">Повторите пароль</label>
<input type="password" id="password2" readonly placeholder="Скрыт в целях безопасности" value="" aria-required="true" class="error" aria-invalid="true" />
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Можете еще немного поправить, чтобы и во втором input после нажатия на кнопку "сохранить" появлялся placeholder "пароль изменен"?

Comment: Еще нашел один глюк. Если просто начинаешь печатать в input - то кнопка становится неактивной. И только перезагрузка страницы спасает от этого.

Comment: @Nabla придется подождать до понедельника. Я с телефона. Если получится то помогу

Comment: Просто начинаешь печатать. Пароли должны быть равны. А когда начинаешь печатать как они могут быть равны.

Comment: надо менять логику в коде? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да но не сильно

Comment: Можете сами попробовать

Comment: Мне сложно с js к сожалению(

Comment: Ничего страшного в нем нет

Comment: Добрый вечер. Сможете помочь сегодня?

Comment: @Nabla доброй ночи. У нас 23:11. Я извиняюсь. Напомните завтра чуток пораньше.

Comment: хорошо, завтра напомню

Comment: Думаю как-то так хотели?

Comment: Да, но можно ли в первом inputе тоже надпись сделать - Пароль изменен?

Comment: да, можно конечно.

Comment: Во, отлично! Спасибо) щас проверю у себя

Comment: Супер! То, что нужно. Очень рад. Спасибо еще раз. Все работает.